# how to establish a relationship between two columns in one table

Tags: t-sql

I want establish a one-to-one relationship between **two** columns (a program code and a test code) in the **same** table. I want all tests with the same test code to have the same program code.

1. My first thought was to use a UDF to find cases where the same test code corresponds to two different programs. I learned that this won't work because t-sql only checks UDFs in check constraints after `INSERTS` -- not after `UPDATES`
   [why is t-sql allowing me to violate a check constraint that uses a UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438184/why-is-t-sql-allowing-me-to-violate-a-check-constraint-that-uses-a-udp)
2. My next thought was to move the logic from the UDF into the check constraint itself. But t-sql is saying that sub-queries are not allowed in the check constraint. This also means I can't use `EXISTS` syntax (which I think also uses a sub-query).

   `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [oneProgramPerTest] CHECK

   (
       (select COUNT(*) 
        from mydb.dbo.mytable u1 
        inner join 
              mydb.dbo.mytable u2 on u1.testcode=u2.testcode and u1.progcode <> u2.progcode
       )=0
   )`

Unless there is some way to enforce this logic without (1) a udf or (2) a subquery then it seems like I need to create a "dummy" table of program codes and then enforce a one-to-one relationship between test codes from myTable and the dummy table. This seems **really** ugly so there has got to  be a better way. Right?

Comment: Why not just have a FK table that associates a test code with a program code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read about normalization (and if you haven't why are you designing a datbase?). You should havea structure with

```
tableA
id (PK)
programcode
other fields

tableB
programcode (PK)
testcode
```

Add a formal foreign key between the two tables  and define program code as the PK in tableb.
Then to get the data you want:

```
select <Name specific fields, never use select *>
from tableA a
join tableB b on a.programcode = b.programcode
```

Comment: it's a legacy db! it sounds like i need two tables to establish this relationship